# Building Silverlight Toolkit with VS2010 Beta 2

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-3.0

I'm trying to build the latest drop of the Silverlight Toolkit with VS2010 Beta 2.  I get errors on all the projects:

"Analysis of Silverlight assemblies is not supported."

The error code is CA0055.  The error goes away if I uncheck Code Analysis in the project properties.

Builds just fine in VS2008.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS 2010 has code analysis turned on by default but it does not analyze Silverlight assemblies. Simply turn off code analysis in the project properties tab.

The project builds in VS2008 because code analysis is not turned on there by default.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly what's stated.  Code analysis isn't supported for Silverlight applications.  You must have your 2008 settings not setup to try to run code analysis, but 2010 setup to do so.  (Possibly because you installed a different version of 2010 vs. 2008, with different feature sets...  For example, this doesn't happen if you installed 2010 Pro version.).

The solution, of course, is just to turn this off in the project properties.  It should build fine if you do so.